# Get size of an unknown image and change class

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, tumblr

On my Tumblr Theme I want to use a different CSS class for portrait images.
Images, by default, come in via `img`-tag and get's the class `bilder`. But if it's an portrait image, I would like to replace the `builder` class with the `hhcoch` class.

**HTML:**

```
<img src="{..}" />
```

**JavaScript:**

```
    var someImg = $("img");
    if (someImg.height() > someImg.width()){
        $( "img" ).addClass( "hhoch" );
    }
```

**CSS:**

```
.bilder {
    height: auto; /*override the width below*/
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.hhoch {
    min-height: 800px;
    max-height: 800px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Sum up: 
The image should get a different class if it's portrait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the right idea, however that specific jQuery selector you're using is going to return an array of ALL the image tags in your document.

This means you'll want to loop over the array of image DOM nodes and apply your class that way.

```
 var $images = $('.bilder');
 $images.each(function(index, img){
   if(img.height > img.width){  // is it a portrait-image?
     $(img).removeClass('bilder');  // Remove default class
     $(img).addClass('hhoch');  // Add the portrait class
   }
 });
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer. Unfortunately nothing happend.

Comment: Ah close! Portrait images are now as I want them to. But the landcape images (..in this case..) got smaller too.

Comment: Are you adding either of the classes by default? Or are they only getting their class in this loop?

Comment: I've fist added the .bilder class, but nothing happened. After removing all classes from img the JS code worked somehow, but changed all images not only the portrait images.

Comment: Okay, so the goal here is to reclass any images that have the `bilder` class depending on their dimensions?

Comment: Correct.  All images have the builder class, only the portrait images should get a new class, the .hhoch class.

Comment: Still dosen't work. Must be a Tumblr thing. I appreciate your help and work very much!

Comment: Code looks correct to me Danny. Sounds like there's some magic happening behind the scenes with tumblr.

Comment: Okay got it. One last beginner question: why does this only work when I put the code at the end of the HTML-code ? @DannyDelott

Comment: It probably only works when you put the JavaScript at the end of the document because the JavaScript is trying to manipulate DOM objects/elements that haven't finished loading. Placing the JS at the end of the document helps because the browser loads all of the DOM first and then your JS can manipulate it. Using jQuery's $(document).ready(); is another (better?) way around this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried condensing the solution to this:

```
$("img.bilder").each(function(){
  if (this.height > this.width) {
      $(this).removeClass("bilder").addClass("hhoch");
  }
});
```

Because I don't think all those extra lines of code are needed and might be your problem. As others were saying, it will return an array of objects so you need to loop through them all.